# My e-commerce website (Magento) working in Ubuntu but not in Windows, showing adobe flash outdated error

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

Can anybody please help me.

My e-commerce website (Magento) working in Ubuntu but not in Windows system. When i am going to any product, its showing adobe flash plugin is outdated error.

What should I do??

How to update the flash plugin in Magento 1.9.2.4

This is not a browser issue. I have tried in Chrome, Mozilla etc. It's working but when I browse any product it goes to error page.